# While importing using transform map, how to set value for String field having choice list?

Tags: transform, servicenow

I am importing some data using Import Set table and transform map. Data is being imported into cmdb_ci_computer table. This table have two fields (os and discovery_source) of type String, but both have choice list associated with them.

Now, when I create a field map for each of them, my source field is of type String (without choice list) and target field is of type String (with choice list). The Choice Action is set to "create". 
When the transform happens, I get error message "Invalid Table assignment to the Choice record."

If I set Choice Action to "ignore", I don't get this error, but it neither sets value. I must set the value there.

How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We encounter "Invalid Table assignment to the Choice record." error only when the source field and target choice list (in case of this question: OS and Discovery Source) are from two different scopes.

For example, if source field is created in application scope, and if target choice list is in Global scope, you will encounter this error.

If both - source and target - fields are from same source, you do not face this error.

More specifically, you will see this error when you are testing your scoped application on your dev instance only. Once your app is installed on some other instance (for testing purpose/actual deployment), you should not see this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was having same issue.I tried giving numeric value(as per the choice list of target table) and it will take that number as a string and insert accordingly(to choice list) to target table.

Comment: Please, reformulate your answer to indicate that you're sure that it solves given problem.

Comment: Some fields, like state on the Vulnerable Items table have a background Integer value, with a display string value. As @mohdImam mentions, they may need to set this Integer value